# MongoDB date time insertion is not happening perfectly from java

Tags: java, mongodb, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am running the code in my local machine. The mongoDb is also running in the local. So there should be no issue in timezone if I am not wrong. I am writing this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecond();
LocalDateTime date=new LocalDateTime();
DateTime dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(dateTimeFormatter.print(date));

BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
      basicDBObject.put("batchId",batchId);
      basicDBObject.put("batchStatus",BatchStatus.STARTED.toString() );

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>: "+ date.toString());
        basicDBObject.put("startTime",dateTime.toDate());

 mongoTemplate.getCollection(collectionName).insert(basicDBObject);
```

The sysout is printing 2016-12-23T11:24:54.907. In db I am getting 2016-12-23 05:54:54.000Z. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Sumit.

Comment: It is timezone issue. set timezone and then check

Comment: does  TimeZone.setDefault work?

Comment: This is working the way it is designed .Mongo stores datetime in UTC. Change to the desired zone while reading it back from database.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo store time as [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time, set Timezone to local in your program.

`LocalDateTime localtDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney"));`